# Hidden Files/Folders are rearranged with F5 [AutoHotkey]

Tags: autohotkey

The aim of the following AutoHotkey script is to toggle Hidden Files and Folders options which you can find in Folder Options -> View. The problem is that after refresh by F5 through `Send {F5}` the arrangement of my icons on Desktop is undesirably changed.

I need to do REFRESH to see change effects but to keep the order and arrangement of my hidden files and folders placed on my desktop. For example, currently my hidden files and shortcuts are placed to the right side of the desktop but when refresh is completed by my script those hidden files are arranged from the left of Desktop that I don't like.

Please help in this regard.

```
#h::
RegRead, HiddenFiles_Status, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden 

If HiddenFiles_Status = 2 
    RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden, 1 
Else 
    RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden, 2 

send {F5}

Return
```

Comment: Are you sure that the refresh is the reason for the files to be rearranged? I suspect that Windows just doesn't memorize the position of icons once they are hidden, and thus simply reinserting them from left to right when they are being displayed again. You could maybe test it by "unhiding" the files, **not** refreshing, and navigating to the desktop via explorer. Not sure if that'll display the files though.

Comment: @MCL Yes, I am; because my the script is as simple as it is; there is no additional lines. Perhaps the reason for hidden files to be rearranged is that if you place an unhidden file exactly over a hidden file (it is possible because the hidden file is invisible) then when you enable show hidden files option; windows has to decide which icon should be placed on that specific position. To avoid such conflicts; perhaps Windows rearranges the icons from left ro right.

Comment: *"there is no additional lines"* I don't quite follow that explanation. Why does this prove that the refresh is the cause for the rearranging? The `RegWrite` **is** one of the lines, too, and could be the only reason very well.

Comment: There is no point in navigating via Explorer because I need to work on Desktop directly (not from within its folder). By that script, I intended to temporarily get rid of some less important icons (by enabling hide attribute) and to show them when I need them (by enabling 'show hidden files and folders' option via Win+H hotkey)  while keeping arrangement of un/hidden desktop icons.

Comment: The navigation with explorer wasn't a proposal for a solution, it's just a potential method for determining if the refresh is the cause. We can't tackle a problem whose causes we don't know.

Comment: @MCL I tested the script without the line send {F5}; the result was that the hidden icons were not shown on the desktop only until when I pressed F5 through keyboard. Unfortunately, after desktop got refreshed, icons including hidden and unhidden files displayed in left-to-right arrangement.

Comment: And what if you don't refresh and navigate there with explorer after the registry unhide?

Comment: Well, without F5, Desktop folder didn't show the hidden icons; but they were displayed only after folder refresh. This was while the Desktop itself remained unaffected. The hidden desktop icons displayed only when I pressed F5 on Desktop. By the way, un/hidden files on my Desktop again rearranged from left to right.

Comment: Do the suggestions in [this thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/4620-refreshing-desktop-icons-upon-hotkey-event/) help?

Comment: I will check it out and post an answer under your name if there is one. Thanks @MCL

Comment: Shelltools allows you to quick toggle hidden files with the right click http://www.moonsoftware.com/shell_tools

Comment: @Joe Shell-Tools is awesome; however regarding the above issue it behaves like my script. Shell-tools provides "Refresh Icons" that only refreshes the visible icons but doesn't cause hidden icons to be displayed though you check its "Show Hidden Files". You need to do refresh with F5 or right-click which have the same effect as my script has; so it doesn't actually works as wanted. BTW, thanks Joe for your helpful recommendation.

Comment: Right, i just thought that i would throw that in ;)